# How do I delay pressing a button again in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While making a simple game, I faced the problem of implementing the delay of pressing the button again. When you click on the button, the Digging function of this script is performed.
P.S. I'm new to game development and Unity in general, so don't swear too much if the code is terrible.

```
public class DiggingGrave : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _RundomNumberBone, _Chance;
    public GameObject _buttonNewArtefact, _buttonDiggingGrave;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }
    public void Digging()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ButtonWait());
        _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(true);
        _Chance = Random.Range(1, 100);
        Debug.Log(_Chance);
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 1)// Статы деревянной лопаты (60%-кость(2-6 костей);40%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 40)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(2, 6);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
        }
        if(BuyItemUndertaker.i == 2)//Статы костяной лопаты (65%-кость(4-8 костей); 10%-душа(1); 25%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 35)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(4, 8);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 10)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul++;
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 3)//Статы железной лопаты  (70%-кость(8-16 костей); 15%-душа(2); 1%-новый артефакт;14%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(8, 16);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 15)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul +2;
            }
            if (_Chance == 16)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 4)//Статы золотой лопаты  (70%-кость(18-22 костей); 25%-душа(3); 1%-новый артефакт;4%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(18, 22);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 25)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul + 3;
            }
            if (_Chance == 26)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 5)//Статы магической лопаты  (70%-кость(26-34 костей); 29%-душа(4); 1%-новый артефакт;)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(26, 34);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 29)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul + 4;
            }
            if (_Chance == 30)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ButtonWait()
    {
        _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }
}
```

I tried to use Coroutine and IEnumerator in different ways, but all without the result I needed. Please tell me how can I better make it so that the button can be pressed once every 2 seconds?

Comment: put a duration in a variable, detuct time.deltatime from it until its 0 and only when its 0  or less care if the button is pressed

Comment: If you move your `SetActive(true)` line to the end of your ButtonWait Routine, then it should work as expected, disabling the button for 2 seconds after pressed.  The problem is that starting a coroutine does not block the code below, it proceeds immediately.  The only waiting that happens is inside the IEnumerator function.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the couroutine itself does not block anything.
You need to have the delayed code be called from inside it.

To only delay the button re-activating, just move the `_buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(true);` to the end of the coroutine.

```
IEnumerator ButtonWait()
{
    _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(true);
}
```

The way it's structured makes it look like you want the `Digging` code to be delayed too.
I've tried to minimise the changes while showing how it works.
I've changed a few of the method names to clarify what's going on.
Note how the code to be delayed is called after the `WaitForSeconds` call inside of the coroutine.

```
public class DiggingGrave : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _RundomNumberBone, _Chance;
    public GameObject _buttonNewArtefact, _buttonDiggingGrave;
    
    public void Digging()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartDiggingWithDelayCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator StartDiggingWithDelayCoroutine()
    {
        _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        DiggingInstant();
        _buttonDiggingGrave.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void DiggingInstant()
    {
        _Chance = Random.Range(1, 100);
        Debug.Log(_Chance);
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 1)// Статы деревянной лопаты (60%-кость(2-6 костей);40%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 40)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(2, 6);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 2)//Статы костяной лопаты (65%-кость(4-8 костей); 10%-душа(1); 25%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 35)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(4, 8);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 10)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul++;
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 3)//Статы железной лопаты  (70%-кость(8-16 костей); 15%-душа(2); 1%-новый артефакт;14%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(8, 16);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 15)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul + 2;
            }
            if (_Chance == 16)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 4)//Статы золотой лопаты  (70%-кость(18-22 костей); 25%-душа(3); 1%-новый артефакт;4%-ничего)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(18, 22);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 25)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul + 3;
            }
            if (_Chance == 26)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (BuyItemUndertaker.i == 5)//Статы магической лопаты  (70%-кость(26-34 костей); 29%-душа(4); 1%-новый артефакт;)
        {
            if (_Chance > 30)
            {
                _RundomNumberBone = Random.Range(26, 34);
                ScoreCandy._ScoreBone += _RundomNumberBone;
            }
            if (_Chance <= 29)
            {
                ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul = ScoreCandy._ScoreSoul + 4;
            }
            if (_Chance == 30)
            {
                _buttonNewArtefact.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've run it and it works (with mock `BuyItemUndertaker` and `ScoreCandy`) but I have no idea what the rest of it does.

I wish you well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke method for a delay in calling function and time can also be set in this function.

for example :   Invoke("methodNameToCall", 3);
the method called methodNameToCall will be invoke after 3 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)